# How to use the GetLastError function in a Win32 Console Application?

Tags: winapi

I am trying to open a Registry Key using the RegOpenKeyEx function from the Windows API, and have this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int  wmain(int argc, wchar_t*argv [])
{
    HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    LPCTSTR lpSubKey = L"Demo";
    DWORD ulOptions = 0;
    REGSAM samDesired = KEY_ALL_ACCESS;
    HKEY phkResult;

    long R = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, lpSubKey, ulOptions, samDesired, &phkResult);

    if (R == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "The registry key has been opened." << endl;
    }
    else //How can I retrieve the standard error message using GetLastError() here?
    {

    }

}
```

How do I use the `GetLastError()` function to show a generic error message instead of valid any Error Message ID into the `else`?

**Edit:** I know there is a FormatMessage function but have the same problem, I don't know how to use it on my code.

Comment: [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yep, but how do I use the FormatMessage on my example code?

Comment: My comment was making sense until you edited your question. Do try to be more specific next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Registry functions do not use `GetLastError()`.  They return the actual error codes directly:

```
long R = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, lpSubKey, ulOptions, samDesired, &phkResult);

if (R == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    cout << "The registry key has been created." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "The registry key has not been created. Error: " << R << endl;
}
```

If you want to display a system error message, use `FormatMessage()` for that:

```
long R = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, lpSubKey, ulOptions, samDesired, &phkResult);

if (R == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    cout << "The registry key has been created." << endl;
}
else
{
    char *pMsg = NULL;

    FormatMessageA(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
        NULL,
        R,
        0,
        (LPSTR)&pMsg,
        0,
        NULL
    );

    cout << "The registry key has not been created. Error: (" << R << ") " << pMsg << endl;

    LocalFree(pMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
LPCTSTR lpSubKey = L"Demo";
DWORD ulOptions = 0;
REGSAM samDesired = KEY_ALL_ACCESS;
HKEY phkResult;


char *ErrorMsg= NULL;

long R = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, lpSubKey, ulOptions, samDesired, &phkResult);

if (R == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{

    printf("The registry key has been opened.");
}
else //How can I retrieve the standard error message using GetLastError() here?
{
     FormatMessageA(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS |       FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
    NULL,
    R,
    0,
    (LPSTR)&ErrorMsg,
    0,
    NULL
);

      printf("Error while creating Reg key.");

}
```